# Can I hold on to an instance of a SymmetricAlgorithm or must it be disposed frequently?

Tags: cryptography, .net-core

So, I have an API that frequently encrypts and decrypts sensitive values. I'm using [`System.Security.Cryptography.Aes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx). It works fine, but I'm curious about the lifecycle of these objects.

The examples all show using `SymmentricAlgorithm` instances in a `using` statement.

```
using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create()) { ... }
```

However, I'd like to know if I can store one for the lifecycle of the application...

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/src/System/Security/Cryptography/SymmetricAlgorithm.cs) for a variety of these classes. On `Dispose`, they seem to only clear out internal properties (the `byte[]` key, for example).

---

What's odd is, in these examples, the `ICryptoTransform` is not disposed either explicitly or in a `using` statement and it also implements `IDisposable` and contains some of the same sensitive information!

```
ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();
```

Comment: I believe that it is a good security practice to immediately dispose of sensitive information after use and not hold it longer than necessary. Holding the object throughout the lifecycle of the application would make it more susceptible to exploits that could read its memory and retrieve sensitive information. That is why the Aes object is placed inside a using statement, to dispose of it as soon as it is not needed anymore.

Comment: @M.F. this is a good comment and could probably be an answer on its own... how does this relate to the key and IV that I'm storing somewhere on the system already, probably in an environment variable. Is that more or less susceptible to similar "attacks"?

Comment: This is crypto, so err on the side of security.  Dispose early and dispose often.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean I believe it is, probably even more than the Aes object. As Maarten already mentioned in his answer, there are ways to protect the key too, e.g. by relying on key stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [M.F. has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798833/can-i-hold-on-to-an-instance-of-a-symmetricalgorithm-or-must-it-be-disposed-freq/49804134#comment86612347_49798833) it is probably better to create and dispose of these kind of objects as soon as possible. Yes, the key may have to be kept if it is used later on. But this key could also protected by other means, e.g. if it is inside a key store. Possibly it would be even safer to keep it in the key store when it is not needed.

Ciphers are generally lightweight objects - they don't carry all that much state. Sure, you may have to perform sub-key derivation each time you initialize one (part of AES), but that's generally a relatively lightweight operation.

What you don't want to do is to start *managing* these objects. If you're going to manage them you run the chance of forgetting to dispose of them when required. Furthermore, if you ever run into a situation where you use them interleaved (as in: for multiple threads) then you will get "interesting results".

However, you could debate if you have e.g. a TLS session if you could not just keep the cipher around and destroy the key that you initialized it with. That might be a use case where keeping the cipher around might be beneficial.

Comment: The `SymmetricAlgorithm` objects are just factories, things like sub-key derivation belong to the `ICryptoTransform` objects they create.  So they're rather lightweight.